# Insert Angular component (HTML) dynamically to TineMCE editor on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to add components which has table, header, footer on button click to the editor. But it's not rendering. Below is what i've tried & what i'm looking for.

This works ->

```
putTemplateInEditor = () => {
  let parentEditor = parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
  parentEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<h2>Hello</h1>');
```

}

This doesn't ->

```
putTemplateInEditor = () => {
  let parentEditor = parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor;
  parentEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<app-bill-header></app-bill-header>');
```

}

Any idea how to insert Angular components?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a tinymce-angular

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/